# SQL Server: Table name uniqueness

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema

From what I understand; a table name has to be unique in a database. Is this still true when using schemas?
If I have 2 Schemas - Customer and Supplier could I then have a Company table in each?

Comment: Yes, table names are only unique within a schema.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: If you haven't already, I would recommend installing either SQL express, or developer on your local machine. Means you have an instance you can just mess around with, without upsetting anyone, or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Table names are unique across Schema. So You can have a table with the same name across multiple schemes on the same database

For Example : 
I can have a table **dbo.Customers** as well as **Sales.Customer** on the same database